spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server, client question
I have a discovery project and a client project on the service side that I created.
If you're curious, the yml file on the service side
client:
register-with-eureka:
fetch-registry: true
service-url: test
defaultZone:
Why is the service automatically created on the discovery server when I didn't write the above part? Also, why should I write the above part?
Discovry Project yml
eureka:
client:
register-with-eureka: false
fetch-registry: false
service-url:
defaultZone: http://
SampleService Project Application
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SampleApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
log.info("##### SampleApplication Start #####");
SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
log.info("##### SampleApplication Start #####");
}
}

Please learn to use markdown to format your posts.
